# Why can't this iOS app access the network?

Tags: ios, networking, unity-game-engine

My (Unity) app complains that the my iPod does not have network connectivity while the device has full wi-fi connectivity (as evidenced by every other app, including Safari).

This isn't just one API point - all of them (Facebook, StoreKit, etc) claim that the network is not available.

This message is periodically sent to the console from my app:

`<Error>: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.`

which may (I think) be coming from **CoreTelephony**.

Any idea what is causing this?  I get it in debug and adhoc builds.  I do not have any Restrictions (from Settings) active on the device.

The device is iOS 6 and the base sdk is iOS 5.

Comment: Did you use other networking libraries such as `ASIHTTP` ?

Comment: No, only unity plugins.

Comment: Have you checked in settings -> devTools -> Network link coordiner that you don't have 100% loss internet connection?

Comment: Hi, did you find out what the problem was? @Raptor, what if he is using `ASIHTTP` or some other networking library(e.g. `AFNetworking`)?

Comment: Dave did you get the solution for it ? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

The "Could not successfully update network info during initialization." log is shown every time you initialize the CTTelephonyNetworkInfo in a device without SIM card, (iPod touch or iPad without 3G).

If it's very annoying, you can just initialize it once and do your network checks against that instance.

Comment: Oh! you rocks, daswift. That's exactly why I was getting this anoying message on simulator. Thanks!

Comment: I tried set location in simulator and CTTelephonyNetworkInfo initialization in appDelegate.m but not working, could you post the code? @rockdaswift

Comment: @YaoLi you just need to do this once (if needed):

let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

Then pass the object around, every time you do that in the simulator or in a device without SIM card you will get that warning.

Comment: @rockdaswift I don't use CTTelephonyNetworkInfo directly, I only use AFNetworking 3.1.0 to make API request and AFNetworking version 2.0+ does work.

Comment: It's weird, AFNetworking doesn't use CTTelephonyNetworkInfo, maybe it's in another dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Check the developer tools to check if you have accidentally turned on 100% loss internet. It should be in the debug menu.

Comment: I have same problem and I couldnt solve this. Network Link Conditioner is not enable in Debug menu

Answer (score 0):

I tried set location in simulator and CTTelephonyNetworkInfo initialization in appDelegate.m but not working. I fixed it by define a new class APIAgent.m:

```
+ (APIAgent *)manager {
    static APIAgent *_manager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _manager = [[APIAgent alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_URL]];
        _manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSMutableIndexSet* codes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: NSMakeRange(200, 100)];
        [codes addIndex: 400];
        [codes addIndex: 401];
        [codes addIndex: 404];
        [codes addIndex: 409];
        [codes addIndex: 500];
        _manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = codes;
    });

    return _manager;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

    [self setHeaders];

    return self;
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress))uploadProgress
                     complete:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject, NSError *error))complete {
    return [self GET:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if (complete) {
            complete(task, responseObject, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if (complete) {
            complete(task, nil, error);
        }
    }];
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters complete:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject, NSError *error))complete {
    return [self POST:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if (complete) {
            complete(task, responseObject, nil);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if (complete) {
            complete(task, nil, error);
        }
    }];
}


- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress))uploadProgress
                      success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure {
    self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // self signed certificate
    self.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
    return [super GET:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:success failure:failure];
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters
                      progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress))uploadProgress
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [parameters mutableCopy];

    self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // self signed certificate
    self.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
    return [super POST:URLString parameters:params progress:nil success:success failure:failure];
}

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id<AFMultipartFormData>))block
                      progress:(void (^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress))uploadProgress
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, id))success failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))failure {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [parameters mutableCopy];

    if (parameters == nil) {
        params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    } else {
        if (parameters[@"postId"] != nil) {
            params[@"postId"] = parameters[@"postId"];
        }
    }

    self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808249/problems-with-ssl-pinning-and-afnetworking-2-5-0-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012
    self.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
    return [super POST:URLString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:block progress:nil success:success failure:failure];

}

- (void)setHeaders {
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[[NSDate alloc] init] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer * serializer = self.requestSerializer;
    [serializer setValue:time forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-API-TIME"];
    [serializer setValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-UUID"];

    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    NSString *preferredLang = [NSLocale preferredLanguages].firstObject;

    [serializer setValue:preferredLang forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-USER-LANGUAGE"];
}
```

Comment: The above code could be used as a utility class to make network request.