# AFNetworking SSL Request

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking

I user AF to send https request like

```
    [self.manager POST:downloadURLStirng parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (success)
            success(responseObject,passParameters);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if(failure)
            failure(operation.responseObject,error,passParameters);
    }];
```

and i have already set securityPolicy to YES

```
    self.manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
self.manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = OPENSSL;
```

but i still got **code -1012** and **error_message : In order to validate a domain name for self signed certificates, you MUST use pinning.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with SSL Pinning and AFNetworking 2.5.0 (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808249/problems-with-ssl-pinning-and-afnetworking-2-5-0-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012)

Answer (score 1):

This is sets security policy to allow invalid certificates and stops domain name validation also.:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy 
policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

[securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
```

Answer (score -4):

I searched for this line

'NSLog(@"In order to validate a domain name for self signed certificates, you MUST use pinning.");'

and below this line I changed

'return NO;'
to

'return YES;'

and it did the magic.

Thanks.

Comment: This is working for me too but it is questionable if this is a good approach. Will give this a try first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808249/problems-with-ssl-pinning-and-afnetworking-2-5-0-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012

Comment: Rather allocate with: `[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];`

Comment: Why did you do this? What problem did it solve, and what advantages did it introduce?