# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807) error while log in

Tags: ios9

I have tried all the solutions provided but still getting same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you actually want to do? Some code sample would be helpful.

Comment: when i am trying to login with http it's working but for https it's not working and showing this error.

Comment: You can check this link for answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808249/problems-with-ssl-pinning-and-afnetworking-2-5-0-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012