# AFNetworking 3 issue

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

In `AFNetworking` 3 for invalid SSL certificate I used **validatesCertificateChain = false** , but now it seems that this field was removed and I can't make requests to my server.

**Here is class for requests:**

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking

class ClientHTML: AFHTTPSessionManager {
    private static var __once: () = { () -> Void in

        let securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.certificate)
        securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false
        securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true
        sharedInstanceTemp.securityPolicy = securityPolicy


        sharedInstanceTemp.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
        sharedInstanceTemp.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()


    }()

    fileprivate static let sharedInstanceTemp = ClientHTML(baseURL: URL(string: kServer_urlBilderlings))

    static var sharedInstance:ClientHTML {
        get {
            _ = ClientHTML.__once

            return sharedInstanceTemp
        }
    }
}
```

**I do requests by:**

```
ClientHTML.sharedInstance.post("https://acs-web-test.firstdata.lv", parameters: nil, progress: { (progress) in
            print("progress = ", progress)
        }, success: { (task, response) in
            let data = response as! Data
            let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("success responce = ", html)
        }, failure: { (task, error) in
            print("error = ", error)
        })
```

And according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808249/problems-with-ssl-pinning-and-afnetworking-2-5-0-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012) I have to use `validatesCertificateChain` property. Can anybody help?

Comment: I still see that, allowInvalidCertificates property exists in AFSecurityPolicy in AFNetworking 3.0.0, please refer this document - http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.0.0-beta.1/Classes/AFSecurityPolicy.html

Comment: I use this property, but I need another validatesCertificateChain, I need to set it to false. Please, take a look at this question's best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808249/problems-with-ssl-pinning-and-afnetworking-2-5-0-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012 . They said about this property, but it was afnetworking 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing `let securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.certificate)` to `let securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.none)`

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer which would help someone later on.

Answer (score 2):

For objective-c user `setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES` without SSL Pinning:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *sec = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
[sec setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
[sec setValidatesDomainName:NO];
manager.securityPolicy = sec;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C**

```
static NSString* const kSecurityCertificate = @"xxxxx";

yourManager.securityPolicy = [self customSecurityPolicy];

- (AFSecurityPolicy*)customSecurityPolicy {
   AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
   NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kSecurityCertificate ofType:@"der"];
   NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
   [securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
   [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
   [securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:[NSSet setWithObjects:certData, nil]];
   return securityPolicy;
}
```