# Could not successfully update network info during initialization

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reachability

I get the above mentioned issue all the time when I first launch the app in the day. 
When I first launch the app, I make server calls to get some data and then play animation video. Server calls is in a separate thread than main UI Thread.
Is it something to do with Network Reachability or the animation video ? I think the first part is the major issue but cannot recreate this all the time.

Has anyone experienced the issue ?

Below is the code when I first launch the app.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();


        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in
            Items.setup(); //AFNetworking call
        };

        animationViewController.delegate = self;
        animationViewController.view.autoresizesSubviews = true;
        animationViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleRightMargin];
        animationViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);

        self.view.addSubview(animationViewController.view);    

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't this iOS app access the network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975525/why-cant-this-ios-app-access-the-network)

Comment: but there are no answers on it....And I am seeing the issue on Devices..

Comment: You're not giving us any details of what you do, when you do it, how you do it.

Comment: Its in swift....It compiles and works...

Comment: It is working and I can compile it too...if you want Ill edit it....

Comment: It is a method call to setup the network calls.I have changed the call so that it doesnt look like an array.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue in Xcode 9.1 with below steps.

1.Select Simulator

2.Select Debug from top menu items.

3.Select Location from Debug menu list.

4.Select Apple location.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an exception breakpoint to capture "All Exceptions" in breakpoint navigator. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Turns out in the App/Capabilities, I have Wireless Accessory Configuration with some red warnings. Click the  button automatically solved the problem.

Not sure if it would work for you. I am using Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing this too, fixed it by giving the simulator a default location.  It may be a code smell so watch how you handle the new location permissions in iOS11.

Answer (score -1):

Issue: same with Xcode 9.0 iOS11.
Resolution: new iOS requires you to manually turn on privacy for new deployment apps. Upgrades of the app is not needed. Following these steps:
(1) iPhone "Settings" icon: click
(2) "Privacy": click
(3) "Location Services": click
(4) [Your app]: click on your app
(5) "While Using the App": click

Answer (score -1):

You might have overrided loadView()  without calling super method.

Change

```
override func loadView() {

}
```

To

```
override func loadView() {
  super.loadView()
}
```

Comment: the view controller lifecycle has nothing to do with this issue. besides, [the documentation for that method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) clearly states that your custom implementation should not call `super`.