# Xcode9, only iPhone X "Could not successfully update network info during initialization."

Tags: ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

Xcode 9, other Simulators running well and iPhone X appear this error message，AFNetworking cannot work.

Comment: I noticed this as well. Left my app running on the iPhone X Simulator by accident, and when I came back the console was flooded with those messages. All at either 1 or 20 seconds distance. In my case networking works fine, I'm using vanilla URLSession though.

Comment: In the answers to these questions there might be something useful for you @shenchao. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359304/could-not-successfully-update-network-info-during-initialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't this iOS app access the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975525/why-cant-this-ios-app-access-the-network)

Answer (score 2):

When this happened to me I was able to work around it by following the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359304/could-not-successfully-update-network-info-during-initialization#answer-46831542). That is, setting the Simulator location to Apple.

[image: screenshot of Simulator.app menu item to set location]

Answer (score 0):

even though if by changing location to apple problem not solve try to run it on other simulator like iphone 8 plus or so ,your problem will be solved